# Xampp 1.8.3 localhost phpmyadmin error code 2000#

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp-vm

I need your help to resolve the below issue.

I have installed XAMPP server on a virtual machine having Windows 10. I changed the ports from `80` to `8080` and MySQL from `3306` to `3307`. Still, I am getting an error when I try to access phpMyAdmin using localhost

[image: Xampp contol panel screen shot]

Comment: phpMyAdmin won't be able to connect since your MySQL isn't actually running, according to what you wrote belong. "attempting to start mysql services" should change to some other text (I don't recall what the phrasing is exactly, but something like "MySQL service running" or similar). Look in the MySQL log for details about why the service isn't starting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also change the phpmyadmin configuration to use the new port?

If not do it with the following steps:

1. Open the xampp controlpanel
2. click config behind apache -> then click phpMyAdmin
3. search for the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` and add `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 'your new port number';` under it
4. save the file

Comment: i have made changes in file and restarted the xampp . but still same issue. in control panel its showing "attempting to start mysql services..." please check attached screen shot. suggested changes done in config.inc.php file.